# Swift Segue between VC's with nothing to link

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, segue

I am trying to link two View Controllers within my application but I cannot figure out how to link them without attaching it to my tableview cell. I want it to just be a simple segue with an identifier so I can call perfrom segue with identifier. However, I can only manage to create a segue by dragging it from my cell to the next view controller.

Here is an image of the two VC's that I am trying to link, showing the cell being selected.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJO0w.jpg

I cannot figure out how to do this.

This is the code I am using for the segue, which seems to be correct. I want it to segue when a row is selected and pass the label name of the row that was chosen.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.NameToPass = DietSelectionTableViewCell.TypesOfDiets[indexPath.row]
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "DietInformation", sender: self)
}


// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "DietInformation" {
        if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? DietInformationViewController {
            destinationVC.DietTypeLabelText = self.NameToPass
        }
    }
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
```

Comment: In the scene you are segueing from, ctrl-click the orange circle at the top (which represents the view controller itself) and drag to the view controller you are segueing to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Control-drag from the *view controller itself*. It is represented by the first circle in the rectangle above the scene.

In this image, I've highlighted the thing you should control-drag from:

[image]

Alternatively, you can use the list at the left. Just control-drag from a view controller. Again, I've highlighted the thing you should control-drag from:

[image]